# PostgreSQL: Insert Date and Time of day in the same field/box?

Tags: postgresql, date, time, to-date

After performing the following:

```
INSERT INTO times_table (start_time, end_time) VALUES (to_date('2/3/2016 12:05',
'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'), to_date('2/3/2016 15:05', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'));
```

PostgreSQL only displays the date.

*If possible*, would I have to run a separate select statement to extract the time (i.e. 12:05 and 15:05), stored in that field? Or are the times completey discard when the query gets executed.

I don't want to use timestamp, since I'd like to execute this in Oracle SQL as well.

Comment: What types are `start_time` and `end_time`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`to_date`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-formatting.html) returns... a date. Surprise! So yeah, it's not going to give you the time.

You should be using the `timestamp` data type to store times and functions which return timestamps. So use [`to_timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-formatting.html).

Oracle also has a [`timestamp` data type](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1841) and [`to_timestamp` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm).

In general, trying to write one set of SQL that works with multiple databases results in either having to write very simple SQL that doesn't take advantage of any of the database's features, or madness.

Instead, use a SQL query builder to write your SQL for you, take care of compatibility issues, and allow you to add clauses to existing statements. For example, Javascript has [Knex.js](http://knexjs.org/) and Perl has [SQL::Abstract](https://metacpan.org/pod/SQL::Abstract).

Comment: Okay thanks. Re-assigning the datatype from date to timestamp and then changing to_date() to the, to_timestamp() function, fixed it. Thank you.